# Linked in Integration in Android with out Android Linkedin App

Tags: android, linkedin-api

Actually I have Done Linked In Integration when Linked App in My Device. I need that same action with out Linked in app. Authentication can be done like Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the below code to Login with LinkedIn in Browser

```
    public class LinkedInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private String TAG=LinkedInActivity.class.getSimpleName();
        public static final String LINKED_IN_PEOPLE_PROFILE = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url)?format=json"; // specific basic details
        private static final String API_KEY = "Your Client Key";
        //This is the private api key of our application
        private static final String SECRET_KEY = "Your Client Secret Key";
        //This is any string of your choice we can use.
        private static final String STATE = "My String value";
        //This is the url that LinkedIn Auth 2.0 process will redirect to. We can put whatever we want that starts with http:// or https:// .
        //We use a made up url that we will intercept when redirecting. Avoid Uppercases.
        private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "Your OAuth 2.0 redirect URL in";
        private String accessToken="";
        //These are constants used for build the urls
        private static final String AUTHORIZATION_URL = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization";
        private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken";
        private static final String SECRET_KEY_PARAM = "client_secret";
        private static final String RESPONSE_TYPE_PARAM = "response_type";
        private static final String GRANT_TYPE_PARAM = "grant_type";
        private static final String GRANT_TYPE = "authorization_code";
        private static final String RESPONSE_TYPE_VALUE ="code";
        private static final String CLIENT_ID_PARAM = "client_id";
        private static final String STATE_PARAM = "state";
        private static final String REDIRECT_URI_PARAM = "redirect_uri";
        /*---------------------------------------*/
        private static final String QUESTION_MARK = "?";
        private static final String AMPERSAND = "&";
        private static final String EQUALS = "=";
        private WebView webView, webView1;
        private ProgressDialog pd;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_linked_in);
            //get the webView from the layout
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_web_view);
            //Request focus for the webview
            webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            //Show a progress dialog to the user
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true);
            //Set a custom web view client
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String authorizationUrl, Bitmap favicon) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (pd != null && pd.isShowing()) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String authorizationUrl){                       
                    if (authorizationUrl.startsWith(REDIRECT_URI)) {
                        Log.i("Authorize", "");
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(authorizationUrl);
                        //We take from the url the authorizationToken and the state token. We have to check that the state token returned by the Service is the same we sent.
                        //If not, that means the request may be a result of CSRF and must be rejected.
                        String stateToken = uri.getQueryParameter(STATE_PARAM);
                        if (stateToken == null || !stateToken.equals(STATE)) {
                            Log.e("Authorize", "State token doesn't match");
                            return true;
                        }
                        //If the user doesn't allow authorization to our application, the authorizationToken Will be null.
                        String authorizationToken = uri.getQueryParameter(RESPONSE_TYPE_VALUE);
                        if (authorizationToken == null) {
                            Log.i("Authorize", "The user doesn't allow authorization.");
                            return true;
                        }
                        Log.i("Authorize", "Auth token received: " + authorizationToken);
                        //Generate URL for requesting Access Token
                        String accessTokenUrl = getAccessTokenUrl(authorizationToken);
                        //We make the request in a AsyncTask
                        new PostRequestAsyncTask().execute(accessTokenUrl);
                    } else {
                        //Default behaviour
                        Log.i("Authorize", "Redirecting to: " + authorizationUrl);
                        webView.loadUrl(authorizationUrl);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            //Get the authorization Url
            String authUrl = getAuthorizationUrl();
            Log.i("Authorize", "Loading Auth Url: " + authUrl);
            //Load the authorization URL into the webView
            webView.loadUrl(authUrl);
        }
        /**
         * Method that generates the url for get the access token from the Service
         * @return Url
         */
        private static String getAccessTokenUrl(String authorizationToken){
            return ACCESS_TOKEN_URL
                    +QUESTION_MARK
                    +GRANT_TYPE_PARAM+EQUALS+GRANT_TYPE
                    +AMPERSAND
                    +RESPONSE_TYPE_VALUE+EQUALS+authorizationToken
                    +AMPERSAND
                    +CLIENT_ID_PARAM+EQUALS+API_KEY
                    +AMPERSAND
                    +REDIRECT_URI_PARAM+EQUALS+REDIRECT_URI
                    +AMPERSAND
                    +SECRET_KEY_PARAM+EQUALS+SECRET_KEY;
        }
        /**
         * Method that generates the url for get the authorization token from the Service
         * @return Url
         */
        private static String getAuthorizationUrl(){
            return AUTHORIZATION_URL
                    +QUESTION_MARK+RESPONSE_TYPE_PARAM+EQUALS+RESPONSE_TYPE_VALUE
                    +AMPERSAND+CLIENT_ID_PARAM+EQUALS+API_KEY
                    +AMPERSAND+STATE_PARAM+EQUALS+STATE
                    +AMPERSAND+REDIRECT_URI_PARAM+EQUALS+REDIRECT_URI;
        }
        private class PostRequestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                pd = ProgressDialog.show(LinkedInActivity.this, "", "Loading...",true);
            }
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
                if(urls.length>0){
                    String url = urls[0];
                    URL sourceUrl = null;
                    try {
                        sourceUrl = new URL(url);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try{
                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)sourceUrl.openConnection();
                        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        conn.setDoInput(true);
                        conn.connect();
                        int responsecode = conn.getResponseCode();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Response Code is :"+responsecode);
                        if(responsecode == 200){
                            String result = "", line = "";
                            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
                            {
                                result = result+line;
                            }
                            //Convert the string result to a JSON Object
                            JSONObject resultJson = new JSONObject(result);
                            //Extract data from JSON Response
                            int expiresIn = resultJson.has("expires_in") ? resultJson.getInt("expires_in") : 0;
                            accessToken = resultJson.has("access_token") ? resultJson.getString("access_token") : null;
                            Log.e("Tokenm", ""+accessToken);
                            if(expiresIn>0 && accessToken!=null){
                                Log.i("Authorize", "This is the access Token: "+accessToken+". It will expires in "+expiresIn+" secs");
                                //Calculate date of expiration
                                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                                calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, expiresIn);
                                long expireDate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(IOException e){
                        Log.e("Authorize","Error Http response "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                    catch (ParseException e) {
                        Log.e("Authorize","Error Parsing Http response "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Authorize","Error Parsing Http response "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean status){
                if(pd!=null && pd.isShowing()){
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
                if(status)
                {
                   Log.e(TAG, "Access Token : "+ accessToken);
                }                                   
            }
        };
    }

*
```

activity_linked_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome, If possible update your code so that it might be useful for others.

Comment: @vigneswara-sairam-andavarapu can you please post your code here as I'm searching for same?

Comment: here, I am not able to share my code. please use above activity class and xml UI.